# How to get a trace of the process history in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, task-manager

I recently noticed that there's a program which shows up on task-bar and disappears momentarily (No window shown). This happens periodically. I want to find out what process this is. Is there a way to get a list of previously executed processes in Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:  Download [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Microsoft and run it.  Set up a filter that excludes everything that is currently running.

Then wait - once the new process pops up, it should appear in the monitoring list.

Comment: Is there any way to see it without downloading an external software?

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use [Process History](http://processhistory.sourceforge.net/), no filtering required

It's a free and portable process database.

It's a simple portable .zip download . There is a manual on how to use it on the download site.

As long as Process History is running, you can query processes that have ended via a GUI.

It will run on any version of Windows from 7.

( I am the author of this open source software )